# What is the difference between tf.scatter_add and tf.scatter_nd when indices is a matrix?

Tags: tensorflow

Both [tf.scatter_add](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_add) and [tf.scatter_nd](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd) allow `indices` to be a matrix. It is clear from the documentation of tf.scatter_nd that the last dimension of `indices` contains values that are used to index a tensor of shape `shape`. The other dimensions of `indices` define the number of elements/slices to be scattered. Suppose `updates` has a rank `N`. First `k` dimensions of `indices` (except the last dimension) should match with first `k` dimensions of `updates`.  The last `(N-k)` dimensions of `updates` should match with the last `(N-k)` dimensions of `shape`.

This implies that `tf.scatter_nd` can be used to perform an `N`-dimensional scatter. However, `tf.scatter_add` also takes matrices as `indices`. But, its not clear which dimensions of `indices` correspond to the number of scatters to be performed and how do these dimensions align with `updates`. Can someone provide a clear explanation possibly with examples?

Comment: Thanks, @Shaunshd, I've a same question as yours. And tried many many tests to verify my understandings, but all failed. I'll analyze more  codes, and design more tests to understand how to handle multidimensional indices support in tf.scatter_nd().

Answer (score 1):

@shaunshd , I finally fully understand the 3 tensors relationship in tf.scatter_nd_*() arguments, especially when the indices have multi-demensions. e.g:
indices = tf.constant([[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [3,3,2]], dtype=tf.int32)

Please don't expect tf.rank(indices)>2, tf.rank(indices)==2 is permanently true;

The following is my test codes to show more complex test case than the examples provided in tensroflow's official website:

```
def testScatterNDUpdate(self):
    ref = tf.Variable(np.zeros(shape=[4, 4, 4], dtype=np.float32))
    indices = tf.constant([[0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [3,3,2]], dtype=tf.int32)
    updates = tf.constant([1,2,3,4,5], dtype=tf.float32)
    #shape = (4,4,4)
    print(tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(ref, indices, updates))
    print(ref.scatter_nd_update(indices, updates))
    #print(updates.shape[-1]==shape[-1], updates.shape[0]<=shape[0])
    #conditions are:
    #      updates.shape[0]==indices[0]
    #      indices[1]<=len(shape)
    #      tf.rank(indices)==2
```

You also could understand the indices with the following psudo codes:

```
def scatter_nd_update(ref, indices, updates):
    for i in range(tf.shape(indices)[0]):
        ref[indices[i]]=updates[i]
    return ref
```

Comapring with numpy's fancy indexing feature, tensorflow's indexing features are still very difficult to use and have different using style, not unified as same as numpy yet. Hope the situation could be better in tf3.x

Comment: The website helps me understand tf.scatter_nd() more deeply.
http://www.programmersought.com/article/7979297352/